# is it possible to create a system that is connected a website with the same database

Tags: php, vb.net, phpmyadmin, html

Good day. I have a thesis project. it is composed of a webpage created on php and a system using vb.net 2008.

As of now , they are both connected to the same database.

I am wondering if it is possible that if i packaged the system and live the website, will still be connected with one database? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right (and the question could be better worded), you're asking what happens if you deploy the website on a different server than the one you used to develop it.  The short answer is that, unless the machine hosting the database is accessible to the web server host machine, that you would also have to redeploy the database.

In other words, wherever you move the PHP-based website and VB.NET system, they would need to be able to access the machine hosting the database server.  Otherwise, I see no issue with them both accessing the same database.

Comment: Much appreciated. I got your point and i understand it well. Thank you so much.

Comment: I need some clarifications. Does that mean that whoever is hosting my website, must be also hosting my system? Is that right?